# jfreechart ploting multiple series on different chart and combined into one jpg file

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to plot three series of data (XYSeries) using a linechart. I would like to plot each serie into it's own chart and combined the three chart write it out as a single jpg file. I just found out I can use CombinedDomainXYPlot for this.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartCombinedXYPlotDemo3.htm

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I already found the answer. I want to put multiple chart in to one jpg file. The answer was used CombinedDomainXYPlot. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see. You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188). Adding an original [mcve] will make the answer more useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this completed sample code to generate combined chart using jfreechart.
[image: Combined Chart]

You can find the completed sample code from this link :
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartCombinedXYPlotDemo1.htm